# How to find file extension of base64 encoded image in Python

Tags: python, image, base64, mime-types, file-extension

I have a base64 encoded image that I decode and save into an ImageField in Django. I want to give the file a random name, but I don't know the file extension.

I have "data:image/png;base64," prepended to the string and I know I could do some regex to extract the mimetype, but I'd like to know if there is a best practices way to go from "data:image/png;base64," to ".png" reliably. I don't want to have my handspun function break when someone suddenly wants to upload a strange image filetype that I don't support.

Comment: There is `DataHandler` in Python 3.4. [Its source code suggests that data urls are simple to parse](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1f3242fb0c9c/Lib/urllib/request.py#l1527) to extract `image/png` in all cases (ignoring [some ambiguity with "quoted-string" representation](http://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=2397)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is best practices to examine the file's contents rather than rely on something external to the file.  Many emails attacks, for example, rely on mis-identifying the mime type so that an unsuspecting computer executes a file that it shouldn't.  Fortunately, most image file extensions can be determined by looking at the first few bytes (after decoding the base64).  Best practices, though, might be to use [file magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29) which can be accessed via a python packages such as [this one](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/filemagic/) or [this one](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic).

Most image file extensions are obvious from the mimetype.  For gif, pxc, png, tiff, and jpeg, the file extension is just whatever follows the 'image/' part of the mime type.  To handle the obscure types also, python does provide a standard package:

```
>>> from mimetypes import guess_extension
>>> guess_extension('image/x-corelphotopaint')
'.cpt'
>>> guess_extension('image/png')
'.png'
```

Comment: The mimetype is already there - using libmagic will only find the mimetype, not suggest an extension.

Comment: Are you suggesting that getting mime type via `filemagic` is safer than using the provided mime type directly?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian In my experience, even with non-hostile emails, many of the provided file types are wrong.  Provided mime types may have been nothing more than a table look up of the file extension.

Comment: Libmagic is obviously the safest way to determine mime type, however it is not always sufficient for determining extension (as the question now states). One danger of using the mime subtype as file extension is that some (obscure) mime types contain a `+` which is cannot be used in FAT file names and so would produce errors on some systems.

Comment: @Graeme That is a good thought.  To get more data, I just did `grep '+' /etc/mime.types` and found two extensions with plus signs, both related to c++ source code.  The more extensive search `[ ext for ext in mimetypes.types_map if '+' in ext ]` yielded the same result.  Also, after a review of `grep image /etc/mime.types`, I found no non-ascii characters in the suggested extensions.

Comment: I'm surprised `.c++` is there, I don't thinnk have never seen it used, `.cpp` or `.cc` are far more common. I never really thought about why (c++ is more descriptive), now I know! Getting an image/svg+xml file on the web is conceivable though.

Comment: @Graeme I have not seen it in the wild either. Separately, my /etc/mime.types maps 'image/svg+xml' to a simple 'svg' or 'svgz'.

Comment: This worked great for my purposes. The only thing that is funny is that on my dev machine 'image/jpeg' maps to '.jpe'. Some snooping around on the net revealed that this is because of the /etc/mime.types entry and how python chooses to order dictionaries. Turns out that browsers understand '.jpe' fine though, even if it initially freaked me out.

Comment: @ChrisDelGuercio I often edit the system mime.types (or provide my own at ~/.mime.types) just for the purpose of overriding things like that.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like [`mimetypes` stdlib module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html) supports data urls even in Python 2:

```
>>> from mimetypes import guess_extension, guess_type
>>> guess_extension(guess_type("data:image/png;base64,")[0])
'.png'
```

Comment: It returns '.jpe' for 'image/jpeg' =(

Comment: Returning .jpe works fine for me since the browsers I've checked (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari) display files named as such fine.

Answer (score 4):

Assume having base64 encoded in variable `encoded_string`, below code works for me:

```py
from base64 import b64decode
import imghdr

encoded_string = 'image base64 encoded'

decoded_string = b64decode(encoded_string)
extension = imghdr.what(None, h=decoded_string)
```

Answer (score 3):

I have Written code in Lambda which will find the type of an image and also checks base64 is image or not.

The following code will sure help someone.

```
import base64
import imghdr
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    image_data = event['img64']    # crate "json event" in lambda 
                                   # Sample JSON Event ========>  { "img64" : BASE64 of an Image }
                                   # Get BASE64 Data of image in image_data variable.
    sample = base64.b64decode(image_data)      # Decode the base64 data and assing to sample.

    for tf in imghdr.tests:
        res = tf(sample, None)
        if res:
            break;
    print("Extension OR Type of the Image =====>",res)
    if(res==None): # if res is None then BASE64 is of not an image.
            return {
            'status': 'False',
           'statusCode': 400,
           'message': 'It is not image, Only images allowed'
          }
    else:
        return 'It is image'
```

Note :- The Above code is written Lambda (AWS) in python, You can copy and paste the following code to your local machine and test it as follows.

```
import base64
import imghdr
image_data = "BASE64 OF AN IMAGE"
sample = base64.b64decode(image_data)      # Decode the base64 data and     assing to sample.

for tf in imghdr.tests:
    res = tf(sample, None)
    if res:
        break;
print("Extension OR Type of the Image =====>",res)
if(res==None):
    print('It is not image, Only images allowed')
else:
    print('It is image')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the mimetypes module - http://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html

Basically `mimetypes.guess_extension(mine)` should do the job.