# Django - how to create a file and save it to a field in ModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

- I have a model with a `FileField` namely `file_test`
- I would like to manually create a file and assign in to `file_test` in the serializer
- Below are my code, would like some help. Thanks

  ```
  class Test(models.Model):
      file_test = models.FileField(storage=OverwriteStorage(),
                                upload_to=_get_landmark_upload_path, max_length=100, blank=True)

  class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      test = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)

      class Meta:
          model = Test
          fields = ('file_test','test')

      def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
          self.file_test.save('test.txt', ContentFile(self.validated_data['test']))
          return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  ```
- Or is there a way to create a file and assign it to `file_test`?
- example in serializer

  ```
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      kwargs['file_test'] = ?????(how to create this file)
      return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  ```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50575902/saving-base64imagefield-type-using-django-rest-saves-it-as-raw-image-how-do-i-c/50693479#50693479  Use this solution `Base64ImageField`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I'd manage to solve the issue by using ContentFile
- Look at example below

  ```
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      kwargs['file_test'] = ContentFile(
          self.validated_data['test'], name="test.txt")
      return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  ```