# Get filetype from BASE64 file

Tags: python, base64

What is the way to get file type from base64 string?

- I need a solution which will work on Windows and Linux(Centos7)

E.G.: This is string ; `eHh4eHh4` which is = to a text file with `xxxxxx` inside.

If websites can do this, I guess it is possible to do it in python:
https://base64.guru/converter/decode/file
[image]

What I have tried:

- using `magic`
- using `imghdr`

Comment: How and what did you explicitly try ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer These ones... `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034201/how-to-find-file-extension-of-base64-encoded-image-in-python` , `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57785500/how-to-know-mime-type-of-a-file-from-base64-encoded-data-in-python`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write the base64 content into BytesIO:

```
import base64
import magic  # https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/
import io

data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+P+/HgAFhAJ/wlseKgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='

bytesData = io.BytesIO()
bytesData.write(base64.b64decode(data))
bytesData.seek(0)  # Jump to the beginning of the file-like interface to read all content!
print(magic.from_buffer(bytesData.read()))
```

Out:

```
PNG image data, 1 x 1, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
```